# Remove similar rows after merging 2 files notepad++

Tags: merge, notepad++

i have two files file1.txt and file2.txt both contain clients mailist i wanna do:
- Merging the files.
2- exclude the similar entrie from both file
example:

file1.txt

```
email1
email2
email3
email4
```

file2.txt

```
email5
email6
email4
email1
email8
```

Result it will be:

```
email2
email3
email5
email6
email8
```

How to do this with Notepad++ or any other program.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a three step approach:

1. merge the files by copying their line in a single file
2. sort the merged file: Edit -> Line Operatoions -> Sort Lines Lexicographically ( you need a current version of notepad++ for this menu function, see [the answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/762279/sorting-lines-in-notepad-without-the-textfx-plugin))
3. remove duplicated lines by a search and replace:

   - Find what: (.*)\r\n\1\r\n
   - Replace whith: (leave empty)
   - select Regular expression in the lower left and click on Replace or Replace All
   - use \r\n for Windows files and use only \n for unix files

The regexp searches for something (.*)  that is repeated in the next line (that is the \1 between the lineendings and replaces the matched two lines with nothing, i.e. removing them.